# JK Status page 404 error

Tags: iis, tomcat8, mod-jk, isapi-redirect

I'm trying to configure IIS + ISAPI redirect + Tomcat.
So, I need to check JK status page, but it throws an error 404.

Here is uriworkermap.properties:

```
/webtier*=loadbalancer
/jkstatus*=jkstatus
```

Here is workers.properties:

```
worker.list=loadbalancer,jkstatus

worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.host=xxx
worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=1

worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.host=xxx
worker.tomcat2.port=8010
worker.tomcat2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2

worker.jkstatus.type=status
worker.jkstatus.mount=/jkstatus
```

I'm trying to access JK by http://xxx/jkstatus, https://xxx/jkstatus but it throws an error 404.

What is wrong with JK? Why it is not accessible?

Comment: Did you create the virtual directory `jkstatus` in the IIS manager? I think you should create it otherwise.

Comment: no, jkstatus virtual dir is not necessary. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved.
I had a mistake in isapi.redirect.properties.
Right variant is:

extension_uri=/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll